# Word break in html and css

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to display the word from `ADIDAS SUPERSTAR LIMITED EDITION*` to `**ADIDAS SUPERSTAR.....**` by using CSS. When i tried to use break-word in css but does not work for it. How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: CSS `word-wrap` won't change the text it is breaking, it only _wraps_ words that do not fit the element. You're looking for string _truncating_.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't know CSS3 supports this :)

Comment: finally solve it ~

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use text-overflow:

```
.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```